# import a class and use the method python

Tags: python, plone, python-2.4

I have a file structure like this:
products

```
-product
  - content
    - MyContent.py
  - Tool.py
```

In Tool.py, I have

```
from AccessControl import ClassSecurityInfo
from OFS.SimpleItem import SimpleItem
from Products.CMFCore.utils import UniqueObject

class Tool(PropertyManager, UniqueObject, SimpleItem):

    @staticmethod
    security.declarePublic('convert_to_lower')
    def convert_to_lower(data):
        return data.lower()
```

In MyContent.py, I Tool access this class method, so I did:

```
from Product.Tool import Tool
from Product.Content.ATContentTypes.content.base import ATCTContent
class MyContent(BaseContent):
      def new_definition(self):
          print Tool.convert_to_lower("ABCD")
```

I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong here. I instantiate the object of MyContent with:

```
mycontent = MyContent()
mycontent.new_definition()
```

But, when I run it, it gives me error saying that the method convert_to_lower is not defined. 
Note: the convert_to_lower() is just a simple example of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You probably made a typo in your example; the correct spelling would be `@staticmethod`, not `@staticclass`. Since the latter would produce a name error I'm sure you knew that already. :-)
- There is no point in putting a security declaration on a static method, that's only applicable to class methods (the declaration is stored on the class, not the method).
- The decorator is being applied to the result of the security declaration line, not the function definition below it. In other words, you now have a `None` static method on your class.

The *usual* way to provide such utility methods in Plone is to use a [ZCA utility registration](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/five.grok/core-components/utilities) though, not a static method.

Comment: The @staticclass was my mistake here, in my own case I had put it as @staticmethod!

Comment: I did not understand why did we need to create 2 interfaces, and where should I store this file with interfaces. While extracting it from the client side, I only need ILanguagePreference, so why is there need to create this another interface called ILanguage, and I also noticed that this ILanguage is used as schema for the 2nd interface. Can you please explain it to me? Could I only use the single interface called ILanguagePreference, and if I do so, what should I place in the schema?

Answer (score 0):

The approach above appears weird. Your tool uses PropertyManager, UniqueObject, SimpleItem as base classes - this implies that your tool is a persistent object. So you want to get hold of the tool by using

```
my_tool = getToolByName(self, tool_name)
result = my_tool.my_method()
```

Or you implement your functionality as a Zope utility and look it up using getUtility().

However writing a persistent tool and then trying to just important the tool does not make much sense. If your code does not deal with persistent object or is just a utility method having nothing in mind with core Zope or Plone functionality: make it a "normal" class without the base classes above and import it they you are trying to do.